# How to type a function that receives a Svelte component

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-component

I have a component with a prop that is an async function that should a Svelte Component

liek this

```html
// MyComponent.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    export let icon: () => Promise<any>;
</script>

// do some stuff with icon...
```

And I'd like to type that parameter, instead of using any.

I tried with the following:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import type { ComponentType } from 'svelte';
    export let icon: () => Promise<Component>;
</script>
```

But when calling it like this:

```html
<MyComponent icon={() => import('./Logo.svelte')}>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Type 'Promise<typeof import("./Logo.svelte")>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ComponentType<SvelteComponentTyped<any, any, any>>>'.

Type 'typeof import("./Logo.svelte")' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<SvelteComponentTyped<any, any, any>>'.

Type 'typeof import("./Logo.svelte")' provides no match for the signature 'new (options: ComponentConstructorOptions<any>): SvelteComponentTyped<any, any, any>'. (ts)
```

Also tried with `export let icon: () => Promise<typeof SvelteComponent>;` as stated [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/486) and I the this error:

```
Error: Type 'Promise<typeof import("./Logo.svelte")>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<typeof SvelteComponentDev>'.

Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'typeof import("./Logo.svelte")' but required in type 'typeof SvelteComponentDev'. (ts)
```

Any idea how to achieve it?

Note: I've been following this article: https://www.viget.com/articles/typing-components-in-svelte/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`() => Promise<ComponentType>` is correct if you account for the fact that the dynamic import returns a module.

Either adjust the usage to:

```js
import('./Logo.svelte').then(m => m.default)
```

Or change the type to `() => Promise<{ default: ComponentType }>` and extract the default export within the component.